# Duplicating values in a column

Tags: r, rep

I have a df:

```
> df
# A tibble: 3 x 2
   Class word    
   <fct> <chr>   
 1 Y     nature
 2 Y     great
 3 Y     are
```

I would like to repeat each value in `word` a specific number of times. For example, I want to repeat it 4 times:

```
> df
# A tibble: 12 x 2
   Class word    
   <fct> <chr>   
 1 Y     nature
 2 Y     nature
 3 Y     nature     
 4 Y     nature
 5 Y     great
 6 Y     great
 7 Y     great
 8 Y     great
 9 Y     are
10 Y     are
11 Y     are
12 Y     are
```

How do I do this using `rep()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `uncount`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    uncount(4) %>%
    as_tibble
```

---

Or with `rep`

```
df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), each = 4),]
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use this:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% slice(rep(1:n(), each = 4))
```